# Why isn't the user with id #1 able to edit the user details?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-6

I have one site in Drupal 6. When I log in as user #1, and I visit the page at user/[uid]/edit, I am not able to access this page. I get an access denied error.

Can any one please tell me what may be the problem, and the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the problem with any of your custom code. Somewhere in the code you might have written some condition and because of that you are facing this problem. Just check your custom code & it can be somewhere like access callback.

**Another approach :**
If many developers are working on the project & SVN(or any version control) is configured, then simply by going back to any revision you can find the code which is making problem for you. 
 Hope it will help you.